# Can you help me recover this message?

Tags: cipher, real

So, in May 2018, a friend and I were sitting in study hall, bored. Both of us had finished our homework early, and we were trading ciphers over email. I sent something that I had encoded, and neither she nor I could decode it (the rest of the email chain is her discussing my attempts at decoding it). From this email thread, I know it’s not:

- a cipher involving moving one key to the right on a keyboard
- something involving underlined vowels which was related to binary.
- rot13.

The whole conversation: (names and stuff obviously redacted)

> BW: Happy theee rythm alt'ae chill queue that's taeip queau Sadie thiss !!!!!
> Other: I hate people!!!!!
> Other: fpm'y er s;;
> Other: yjr lrunpstf upi ofopy
> BW: ???
> Other: keyboard
> BW: Don’t we all.
> BW: The keyboard you idiot.
> BW: Ztzlcg, lae L rlydsmv Xers wbqdmh fyzmy dgz.
> Other: what?? There’s nothing to the right of z
> BW: *link to a Bifid cipher solver*
> *2 hours later*
> Other: thanks, Bifid cipher. You suck. *BW*, you can’t decipher your own message?
> BW: maybe, maybe, it might have been a different cipher. maybe playfair?
> Other: *several comments about my inability to remember a single cipher and key removed*

I apparently believed it was the Bifid cipher, Playfair cipher, or something with a key. The message is below, in its entirety. The previous cipher translated to “don’t we all the keyboard you idiot” so I assume this might be a response.

Can you help me recover it? (This is to prove a point to a different friend.)

> Ztzlcg, lae L rlydsmv Xers wbqdmh fyzmy dgz.

What I have so far is that *maybe* L translates to I, and Xers might be her name (Ella). I’m just guessing.

Comment: For anyone who might try shifting each letter by a certain number, no, that's not the solution.

Comment: Welcome to PSE! I'm not sure I understand the situation fully: you wrote that you encoded the message yourself, but then you suggest that you do not know what cipher it was? would you be able to clarify?

Comment: I wrote it, but according to the email logs, within 2 hours I had lost the key and any notes I had on decoding it.

Comment: Is it possible that this is a homebrew encryption algorithm with a key, or are you fairly sure it's a known cipher?

Comment: @LukasRotter: Fairly sure it’s a known cipher, as I sent emails with a link to an online cipher solver for Bifid and Playfair ciphers (which are unfortunately no longer available). Also, I wasn’t really into creating my own ciphers back then.

Comment: I think we can exclude a playfair cipher, as the number of letters is odd. I nevertheless performed a quick dictionary attack (with about 400k words) for playfair, bifid and vigenere - No luck